# getting form data of pdf file through javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I am working on a form, which is in pdf format.
 I want to get the form's values through JavaScript or PHP from that pdf file, and want to store that in a database.

How can i do it?

Comment: Have you tried to do it? What do you mean by form in pdf format?

Comment: I mean the forms(input fields) are in pdf format, and i want to grab the values from that

Answer (score 0):

If I managed to understand, you want to get values from pdf file, and put them in database. The only way I can think of is through using OCR. 
Here is javascript OCR: 
http://antimatter15.com/ocrad.js/demo.html